# How can I make a back button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am not sure how to code a back button for a a SwiftUI view to return to the main content view. Mainly because I am using a sidebar menu that is why I cannot use the navigation link to the view and back.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var btnBack: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            .font(Font.system(size: 21, weight: .medium))
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
       btnback
       Text("Some Text")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: this view is another swiftui view file and it doesn't work it says btnback,type cannot conform to 'view' only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: I also realised you had no struct view but I have one so I might be doing it wrong maybe

Comment: I didn't add those code which I thought is absolute "basic". I edited my post again.

Comment: this don't make sense, I want to have two separate ui files and navigate back to another one, these is two views in one file kind of viewing which I don't want.